# how to uncheck checkbox that has specific dynamic value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I have many checkboxes that when user checks one of them, it makes a span with ajax with 'tag' attribiute .

I want that when a user click in this spans again, unchecks the checked checkbox, but when I put 't' var in front of value its not working, can anybody help me?

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clear-tags', function() {
  var t = $(this).attr('tag');
  $(":checkbox[value=t]").prop("checked", "false");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tags-res">
  <span class="clear-tags" tag="wb=38"></span>
  <span class="clear-tags" tag="attr=33|998"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML to make a [mcve]

Comment: It is best practice to avoid using `var` in modern JavaScript as you are likely to find issues with scope (to over-simplify: it will act as if you declared it before you did). Instead you should always use `const` for unchanging values as in the accepted answer, and `let` for values that change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `t` as a variable. Also you need to quote the value of the attribute to use in a selector when it has special characters in the selector.

You may even have to escape some characters using [CSS-Escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape)

Here I toggle the checkbox on click of the span and quote it using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clear-tags', function() {
  const t = $(this).attr('tag');
  const $chk = $(`:checkbox[value="${t}"]`);
  $chk.prop("checked", !$chk.prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tags-res">
  <span class="clear-tags" tag="wb=38">wb=38</span>
  <span class="clear-tags" tag="attr=33|998">attr=33|998</span>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" value="wb=38" />
<input type="checkbox" value="attr=33|998" />
```

Comment: thanks very much , it worked :)) , its my first question in this platform.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `t` as a string. You have to concatenate it instead and use as a variable.

```
$(document).on('click', '.clear-tags', function() {
  var t = $(this).attr('tag');
  $(`:checkbox[value="${t}"]`).prop("checked", "false");
});

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tags-res">
  <span class="clear-tags" tag="wb=38"></span>
  <span class="clear-tags" tag="attr=33|998"></span>
</div>
```